# Focus method from window object doesn't work in IE(2020)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

MDN says that window.focus() is compatible with IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus.

But if I open IE and write

```
x=window.open('https://blank.org')
```

And after I come back to the main tab and I do `x.focus()` is not working.

I found several similar posts, but they are all old, and the information referred to there is out of date.

Is this happening by default, or is a IE setting?

Comment: does your code works in modern browsers?

Comment: Yes, it works in all of them

Comment: do you get an error in the browser developer tools console? have you read the part of that page you posted that says *It may fail **due to user settings** and the window **isn't guaranteed to be frontmost** before this method returns* - so, yes, there may be an IE setting

Comment: No error in console. From IE settings I checked the option "Always switch to new tabs when they are created" as suggested in older posts, but is not working.

Comment: well, IE is pretty old - maybe there's a different setting somewhere else, like in MSPaint or something (joking, but windows does do weird stuff with settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue in IE 11. I searched docs and find that it might be due to some security issues the method can't be used in IE 8+. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh771938(v=vs.85)):

> Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. The **focus** method no longer brings child windows (such as those created with the **open** method) to the foreground.

It can work in modern browsers because they have different engines than IE so the function can work.